# Formatting text in UltraTooltipManager

Tags: text, tooltip, infragistics

I need to show a tooltip say "Name: Sam", where the characters "Sam" will be bold. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try the following code

```cs
UltraToolTipInfo tipInfo = new UltraToolTipInfo();
tipInfo.ToolTipTextStyle = ToolTipTextStyle.Formatted;
this.ultraToolTipManager1.SetUltraToolTip(this.YourControl, tipInfo);
this.ultraToolTipManager1.DisplayStyle = ToolTipDisplayStyle.Office2007;
tipInfo.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
tipInfo.ToolTipTextFormatted = "Name: <span style=\"font-weight:bold;\">Sam</span>";
```

[link](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/?page=Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinToolbars.v11.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.SharedProps~ToolTipTextFormatted.html) to infragistics online help

hope this helps

Comment: Was about to post the same answer as I did some work on it :)

Comment: The following is a link to all of the supported tags and attributes for the formatted text: http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/?page=WinFormattedLinkLabel_Formatting_Text_and_Hyperlinks.html